# How to enable website background image responsive in android webview?

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I have converted a web application into android app, all the functions are working but, the website background image is not responsive after converted into app.

Comment: i think that same flash, which is not running in android ?

Comment: i dont get it please how to run flash in android

Comment: u cannot run flash contents on mobile, some mobile may run most will wont understand flash format. U need take some other approch.

Comment: it is some thing related to css you need to change html behaviour